# how to write a function to process two types of input data in golang

Tags: go, polymorphism

I have multiple `struct`s share some fields. For example,

```
type A struct {
    Color string
    Mass  float
    // ... other properties
}
type B struct {
    Color string
    Mass  float
    // ... other properties
}
```

I also have a function that only deals with the shared fields, say

```
func f(x){
    x.Color
    x.Mass
}
```

How to deal with such situations? I know we can turn the color and mass into functions, then we can use interface and pass that interface to the function `f`. But what if the types of `A` and `B` cannot be changed. Do I have to define two functions with essentially the same implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Go you don't the traditional polymorphism like in Java, c#, etc. Most things are done using composition and type embedding. A way of doing this simply is by changing your design and group the common field in a separate struct. It's just a different of thinking.

```
type Common struct {
    Color string
    Mass  float32
}
type A struct {
    Common
    // ... other properties
}
type B struct {
    Common
    // ... other properties
}

func f(x Common){
    print(x.Color)
    print(x.Mass)
}

//example calls
func main() {
    f(Common{})
    f(A{}.Common)
    f(B{}.Common)
}
```

There are other ways too by using interfaces and getters mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115385/polymorphism-in-go-lang) but IMO this is the simplest way

Comment: Good example +1. A maybe more spelt out version https://play.golang.org/p/UvUabmDf689.